# SQLAlchemy 2 override relationship in validation or before_insert event

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have Class A as follows:

```
Class A(Base):
  # some other fields
  category_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("category.id"))
  category: MappedCategory = relationship(back_populates="a_set")
```

And Class B as follows:

```
Class B(Base):
  a_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey("a.id"),
        index=True,
    )
    a: Mapped["A"] = relationship(
        back_populates="b_set",
    )
  category_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("category.id"))
  category: MappedCategory = relationship()
```

B.category works as a cache for A.category, therefore it should just be copied from A.
I know it's redundant but it is a style exercise.

I tried this solution:

```
class B:
  ...
@listens_for(Class, 'before_insert')
def copy_reference_from_b_to_a(mapper, connection, target):
target.category_id = target.a.category.id
target.category = target.a.category
```

and I got a warning during tests:

```
SAWarning: Usage of the 'related attribute set' operation is not currently supported within the execution stage of the flush process. Results may not be consistent.  Consider using alternative event listeners or connection-level operations instead.
```

I tried also

```
class B:
   #....
   @validates("category_id")
    def sync1(self, key, category_id):
        breakpoint()
        # Copy the reference from Model B to Model A
        # target.category_id = target.a.category_id
        self.category_id = self.a.category_id
        self.category = self.a.category
        return category_id
```

and I got

```
 RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Any chance to achieve this result?